# Invalid archive header at open a dump file

Tags: python, postgresql, dump

I'm using the [pgdumplib](https://pypi.org/project/pgdumplib/) lib. Unfortunately there is an error, when I'm trying to open the file. I'm using Python 3.7

**Code:**

```
import pgdumplib

dump = pgdumplib.load('C:/Users/user/data/test.dump')

print('Database: {}'.format(dump.toc.dbname))
print('Archive Timestamp: {}'.format(dump.toc.timestamp))
print('Server Version: {}'.format(dump.toc.server_version))
print('Dump Version: {}'.format(dump.toc.dump_version))

for line in dump.table_data('public', 'pgbench_accounts'):
    print(line)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/data/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    dump = pgdumplib.load('C:/Users/user/Documents/Documents/data/test.dump')
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\data\lib\site-packages\pgdumplib\__init__.py", line 24, in load
    return dump.Dump(converter=converter).load(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\data\lib\site-packages\pgdumplib\dump.py", line 234, in load
    self._read_header()
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\data\lib\site-packages\pgdumplib\dump.py", line 552, in _read_header
    raise ValueError('Invalid archive header')
ValueError: Invalid archive header
```

Comment: Are you certain that the test.dump file is valid?

Comment: @ewong thanks for the comment. Yes I'm certain that the dump file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

MAGIC: bytes = b'PGDMP'

...

```
def _read_header(self) -> typing.NoReturn:
    """Read in the dump header

    :raises: ValueError

    """
    if self._handle.read(5) != constants.MAGIC:
        raise ValueError('Invalid archive header')
```

....

pgdumplib expect 'PGDMP' as begin dump. Probably, it was in a previous version PostreSQL's dumps.